# Proof verification: $\iint_{R}dA=\iint_{S}\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|dA$ using Green's theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, line-integrals, greens-theorem

In James Stewart's *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* ($8$e), problem $31$ of Section $16.4$ asks us to prove the change of variables formula

$$\iint_{R}dx\text{ }dy=\iint_{S}\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|du\text{ }dv$$

using Green's theorem. Here, $R$ is the image of $S$ under the transformation $T$ defined by the equations $x=g(u,v)$, $y=h(u,v)$. Here's my reasoning:

Notice that $\iint_{R}dA$ is the area of the region $R$. It can be shown that Green's theorem implies that this area is given by the line integral $\int_{\partial R}x\text{ }dy$. Thus, if $\partial R$ can be parameterized by $\textbf{r}(t)=\left<x(t),y(t)\right>$ ($a\leq t\leq b$), we can write

\begin{align*}
\iint_{R}dA &= \int_{\partial R}x\text{ }dy\\
&= \int_{a}^{b}x(t)y'(t)\text{ }dt
\end{align*}

It was assumed that the image of $S$ under $T$ is $R$, so if $T$ preserves orientation, it must be the case that $T$ maps $\partial S$ to $\partial R$. It follows that

\begin{align*}
\left<x(t),y(t)\right> &= \textbf{r}(t)\\
&= T\left(\textbf{r}_{S}(t)\right)\\
&= \left<g(\textbf{r}_{S}(t)),h(\textbf{r}_{S}(t))\right>\\
&= \left<g(u(t),v(t)),h(u(t),v(t))\right>
\end{align*}

for all $t\in[a,b]$, where $\textbf{r}_{S}(t)=\left<u(t),v(t)\right>$ parameterizes $\partial S$ (the parameter domain doesn't change because $\partial S$ is a closed curve, and thus must return to $\textbf{r}_{S}(a)$ once $t$ reaches $b$).

We deduce that

\begin{align*}
x(t) &= g(u(t),v(t))\\
y(t) &= h(u(t),v(t))\\
y'(t) &= h_{u}(u(t),v(t))u'(t)+h_{v}(u(t),v(t))v'(t)
\end{align*}

and consequently

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}x(t)y'(t)\text{ }dt &= \int_{a}^{b}g(u(t),v(t))\left[h_{u}(u(t),v(t))u'(t)+h_{v}(u(t),v(t))v'(t)\right]dt\\
&= \int_{a}^{b}[g(u(t),v(t))h_{u}(u(t),v(t))u'(t)\\
& +g(u(t),v(t))h_{v}(u(t),v(t))v'(t)]dt\\
&= \int_{a}^{b}g(u(t),v(t))h_{u}(u(t),v(t))u'(t)\text{ }dt\\
& +\int_{a}^{b}g(u(t),v(t))h_{v}(u(t),v(t))v'(t)\text{ }dt\\
&= \int_{\partial S}g(u,v)h_{u}(u,v)du+g(u,v)h_{v}(u,v)dv
\end{align*}

Applying Green's theorem gives

\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial S}g(u,v)h_{u}(u,v)du+g(u,v)h_{v}(u,v)dv &= \iint_{S}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(g(u,v)h_{v}(u,v)\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(g(u,v)h_{u}(u,v)\right)\right)dA\\
&= \iint_{S}(g_{u}(u,v)h_{v}(u,v)+g(u,v)h_{vu}(u,v)\\
& -g_{v}(u,v)h_{u}(u,v)-g(u,v)h_{uv}(u,v))\text{ }dA\\
&= \iint_{S}\left(g_{u}(u,v)h_{v}(u,v)-g_{v}(u,v)h_{u}(u,v)\right)dA
\end{align*}

The last expression is precisely $\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|$ (the orientation has not changed), so we may finally write

$$\iint_{R}dA=\iint_{S}\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|dA$$

I appreciate any and all feedback. If you identify any mistakes, I kindly ask that you only give me hints so I can correct them myself.

**Extra**: with a few tweaks, this argument can be used to prove the more general result

$$\iint_{R}f(x,y)\text{ }dA=\iint_{S}f(g(u,v),h(u,v))\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|dA$$

Comment: Yes, this is the proof, modulo details that none of us would bother to check at the level of Stewart. You should put in some more line breaks so that your long equations can be read on the screen.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for taking time to review the proof! I also thank you for your editing suggestion, which I have now included in my post :)

Comment: If you're interested in such questions, probably Stewart's book is not the right book for you for multivariable calculus. You might take a look at some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) for a more sophisticated treatment.